# How to fix the wait operation is timed out?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Whenever the database query is fired it gives the error 'The wait operation is timed out'. So how can I get rid of this error?

> I am using LINQ to get the data.

Comment: The error is self descriptive. You have reached the database connection timeout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that tells you query execution has been dropped to timeout. So, you can refactor the query or increase the command timeout of `_context`;

```
public class SampleDbContext: DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alter the database connectionstring and set the TimeOut property in it.

Comment: [Connection Timeout in the connection string does not change the CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) so it will not solve the problem.  You need to remove the second part as it only pertains to the duration at which a connection is attempted *to the server* will timeout, not *how long queries can run*.

Comment: The CommandTimeout property used for EF (and the created commands) is located in the Database.CommandTimeout property (EF 6.0ff)

Comment: Yes, this is connection timeout not command timeout. It is the only way to set CommandTimeout for context.

Comment: @Rainman Thank you so much . It was really help full and problem has been solved

Comment: @ErikPhilips your comment should be the precise answer to this question, changing the connection string timeout will not fix the error you have to set the SqlCommand object CommandTimeout property, thanks buddy.